# Being a good citizen and web-scraping

Tags: python, screen-scraping, scrapy

I have a two part question.

First, I'm writing a web-scraper based on the [CrawlSpider](http://readthedocs.org/docs/scrapy/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#topics-spiders) spider in Scrapy. I'm aiming to scrape a website that has many thousands (possible into the hundreds of thousands) of records. These records are buried 2-3 layers down from the start page. So basically I have the spider start on a certain page, crawl until it finds a specific type of record, and then parse the html. What I'm wondering is what methods exist to prevent my spider from overloading the site? Is there possibly a way to do thing's incrementally or put a pause in between different requests?

Second, and related, is there a method with Scrapy to test a crawler without placing undue stress on a site? I know you can kill the program while it runs, but is there a way to make the script stop after hitting something like the first page that has the information I want to scrape?

Any advice or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there possibly a way to do thing's incrementally

I'm using Scrapy caching ability to scrape site incrementaly

[HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#std:setting-HTTPCACHE_ENABLED)

Or you can use new 0.14 feature [Jobs: pausing and resuming crawls](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html)

> or put a pause in between different requests?

check this settings:

```
DOWNLOAD_DELAY    
RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY
```

> is there a method with Scrapy to test a crawler without placing undue stress on a site?

You can try and debug your code in [Scrapy shell](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html)

> I know you can kill the program while it runs, but is there a way to make the script stop after hitting something like the first page that has the information I want to scrape?

Also, you can call [scrapy.shell.inspect_response](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html#invoking-the-shell-from-spiders-to-inspect-responses) at any time in your spider.

> Any advice or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Scrapy documentation is the best resource.

Answer (score -2):

You have to start crawling and log everything. In case you get banned, you can add sleep() before pages request.

Changing User-Agent is a good practise, too (http://www.user-agents.org/ http://www.useragentstring.com/ )

If you get banned by ip, use proxy to bypass it. Cheers.

Comment: That's an interesting response to a question about "being a good citizen and web-scraping" :)